# short way of cheeking multiple string in VBA

Tags: vba

What is shortcut of checking string value like this.

```
If midtxt = "a" Then
    midtxt = "apple"
    ElseIf midtxt = "b" Then
        midtxt = "ball"
        ElseIf midtxt = "c" Then
            midtxt = "cat"
         .....
            ElseIf midtxt = "z" Then
               midtxt = "zebra"
End If
MsgBox midtxt
```

Is there any way I can do this using two arrays.

```
[a, b, c....z] and [apple, ball, cat.....zebra]
```

**Edit**

I need reproducible function for my task.

I think a for apple is not right example for me.

This is updated array for me.

```
[ap, bl, ca,... zr]  [apple, ball, cat... zebra]
```

means the two letter code is derived from the corresponding string but it is not uniformly derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Select Case or Switch function

```
Function SwapString(strInput As String)
    SwapString= Switch(strInput = "a", "Apple", strInput = "b", "Banana", strInput = "c", "Cherry")
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

A dictionary may be worthwhile here, as long as the [a, b, ...z] set is unique.

In the VBA IDE, go to Tools, References, and select Windows Scripting Runtime.

```
Public gdctAnimals As Dictionary

Public Sub SetUpAnimalDictionary()
    Set gdctAnimals = new Scripting.Dictionary
    gdctAnimals.Add "a", "apple"
    gdctAnimals.Add "b", "ball"
    gdctAnimals.Add "c", "cat"
    gdctAnimals.Add "z", "zebra"
End Sub

Public Sub YourProc(midtxt As String)
    If gdctAnimals Is Nothing Then
        SetUpAnimalDictionary
    End If

    If gdctAnimals.Exists(midtxt) Then
        MsgBox gdctAnimals(midtxt)
    Else
        MsgBox "Item not found in dictionary", vbExclamation
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: I have no idea about dictionary. I will try your idea and get back. +1 till then.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, if you can only have 26 combinations (a-z) the easiest way is to do this:

```
Public Function ReturnString(strIn As String) As String

    Select Case strIn

        Case "a"
            ReturnString = "apple"
        Case "b"
            ReturnString = "ball"
        Case "c"
            ReturnString = "cat"

        ' .............

        Case Else
            ReturnString = "UNKNOWN"
    End Select

End Function
```

and you call your fonction like this

```
MyLongString = ReturnString "a"
```

But there are many more possibililities that I won't detail because you have not detailed enough your question:

- You can use 2 arrays or a 2D array
- you can use an array of private types
- you can use a dictionary as specified in another answer

Answer (score 1):

No need for an external component or tedious population, you are looking for something based on an ordinal value; `a=>z` is the character code range `97=>122` so you can use a simple efficient array lookup by converting the character code to a value within the bounds of the array:

```
'//populate (once)
Dim map() As String: map = Split("apple,ball,cat,...,zebra", ",")

'//lookup
midtxt = "a"
midtxt = map(Asc(Left$(midtxt, 1)) - 97)

'=>apple

midtxt = "c"
midtxt = map(Asc(Left$(midtxt, 1)) - 97)

'=>cat
```

If needed check the value starts with a character first with `if midtxt like "[a-z]*" then ...`

Comment: Let me understand it.

Comment: This works but I failed to give better example. This sims shortest answer. If the string is fixed this will be very useful. for me every time the parsing string will be different.

Comment: This is certainly the creative example code. Will test and tell.

Comment: Yeah this is not going to work for anything other than single letter lookups